# How to set some attributes specific to my proxy preventing the oiginal object to get it

Tags: python

I wanted to set some attributes specific to my proxy, or to pass attribute to both proxy and original, so i tried the folowing code. I I don't uderstand why: "setattr(self,name, value)" fail with a RecursionError.

```
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj

    # Delegate attribute lookup to internal obj
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._obj, name)

    # Delegate attribute assignment
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name.startswith('_'):
            setattr(self,name, value)    # Call original __setattr__
        else:
            setattr(self._obj, name, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class A:
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x
        def spam(self):
            print('A.spam')

    a = A(42)
    p = Proxy(a)
    print(p.x)
    print(p.spam())
    p.x = 37
    print('Should be 37:', p.x)
    print('Should be 37:', a.x)
    p._y=3
    print('p._y',p._y)
    try:
        print('a._y',a._y)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't uderstand why: "setattr(self,name, value)" fail with a RecursionError.

Because `setattr` calls the `__setattr__` magic method. [The documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__):

> If `__setattr__()` wants to assign to an instance attribute, it should call the base class method with the same name, for example, `object.__setattr__(self, name, value)`.

So do that:

```
…
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name.startswith('_'):
            object.setattr(self, name, value)    # Call original __setattr__
        else:
            object.setattr(self._obj, name, value)
…
```